# U.S. law requires the credit card due date to be on the same day every month. If it's the 30th, what about February?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, law

Out of sheer curiosity, what would the due date be in February if it's normally on the 30th on every other day of the month, considering that the Credit CARD Act of 2009 requires it to be the same day each month?

Comment: This is an idle question that is not really about an actual problem regarding personal finance and money that you are facing, and so here is an idle response. Doesn't setting the due date to the "last day of the month" satisfy the requirement?

Comment: @DilipSarwate "Sheer curiosity" is a sufficient enough reason for asking a question here.

Comment: @BenMiller I disagree. The second sentence of the help for "How to ask a question" on this site reads "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." Even if the OP wishes to sue her credit card company for a violation of the CARD Act by insisting on the due date of her February 2016 statement being February 29 (whereas her normal due date is the 30th of the month), she would be better off consulting her attorney.

Comment: @DilipSarwate You are entitled to your opinion, of course. Any further discussion can go on [this meta question](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/q/2076/10997).

Comment: I guess you don't pay in February's then :)

Answer (score 5):

The answer is simple: The credit card company would avoid having the due date be the late enough in the month make it an issue.

In fact the card company should set a due date so that if the normal due date that month is a Saturday, and Monday was a holiday, then on Tuesday it would still be the same month.

Over the long term the due data makes very little difference to the credit card company. In fact if you ask they will allow you to adjust the due date to fit your pay cycle. I did this when I went to an employer who paid us monthly. It was an easy request. I don't remember if they allowed me to pick virtually any day, or if they had a only some dates they allowed. Starting the next month I had a new due date.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I checked my cards.  Chase allowed any date between the 1st and 28th of the month.  Capital One's allowed dates were spaced 4 days apart, 3, 7, 11, ... 27 (31st not available).  Discover also precludes the 29th-31st, but has a really weird set of [blackout dates](https://i.imgur.com/u54XbH3.png) so I can't be sure the end of the month is precluded for the reason the OP is asking about and not as part of the baseline crazy.